# the selected value was cleared in dropdown after add new criteria in jqgrid advanced searching

Tags: jqgrid, dropdownbox, advanced-search

In jqgrid advanced searching, the value selected in drop down list was cleared after i add new criteria.

Below detail for your reference.

1) in jqgrid column model

```
{name:'instrumentType', 
 index:'instrumentType',
 searchoptions:{
                dataInit:instrumentTypeDataInit,
                sopt: ['eq','ne','nu','nn','in','ni']},    
 align:"left", 
 stype:'select'},
```

2) javascripts function for instrumentTypeDataInit

```
instrumentTypeDataInit=function(el){
    var categoryInstrumentTypeOptions = "${categoryInstrumentTypeOptions}";  
    $(el).append(categoryInstrumentTypeOptions);
  }
```

3) when add criteria "Instrument Type", and select "OPTION", it goes well.

[image]

4) when add another criteria, the value selected is cleared.

[image]

Does anyone know why it is? and what's the solution? thanks a lot.

EDIT:

i've used the dataInit function in the wrong way, used searchOptions.value instead, the issue has been resolved, you can refer another post:[best way to dynamically populate dropdown options in jqgrid advanced searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967720/best-way-to-dynamically-populate-dropdown-options-in-jqgrid-advanced-searching)

Comment: could you provide the demo which demonstrates the problem? It could be jsfiddle demo or any other, but it should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. The code of `instrumentTypeDataInit` seems strange for me. What is `${categoryInstrumentTypeOptions}`? Is it an `<option>` element? Why you **append** it to the select instead of just setting the value as selected? The scenario is unclear for me.

Comment: @Oleg, I just want to dynamically append the options to the select control. ${categoryInstrumentTypeOptions} is string of options, that populated from the server, and then set in request from server. so in ftl page, I use ${} to get the options.

Comment: @Oleg, I checked with another post you replied to me, maybe I use dataInt in the wrong way. will review you post carefully. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've used the dataInit function in the wrong way, used searchOptions.value instead, the issue has been resolved, you can refer [another pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967720/best-way-to-dynamically-populate-dropdown-options-in-jqgrid-advanced-searching)t, Oleg has given an answer: